Generating Stub from WSDL/XML file in nodejs using utility other than Apache CFX
looking for different utility other than Apache CFX to generate stub from WSDL/XML file
Currently we are using Apache CFX to generate the stub(.js) from WSDL/XML file. But we are looking for different utility other than Apache CFX
